# Websocket messages (recieved and sent) found in browsers debugging tools are not humanly readable

Tags: python, json, google-chrome, websocket, tcp

The messages look like this:
[screenshot of the message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNi4l.png)

I can't read the sent and recieved messages in the browsers debugging tools.
I've tried in Chrome and Firefox.

Chrome can give me the messages in a hex format.
This is the first message (last part of the auth token cut out) in a hex format:

```
08f8 cac4 0212 380a 0930 2e30 2e30 2d64 6576 122b 4265 6172 6572 2066 6438 3866 6661 642d 3231 6633
```

I've also tried to get the data in a readable format with WireShark, but I can't seem to find the right packages as the "websocket" filter does not show anything.

Is there any way I can make these messages readable?

Thank you for your time.